# How to exit recursion when condition is met?

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to write a function which prints the minimum number of steps involved to make starting number to target number with multiply by 2 and subtract by 1.

However, I am getting the error:

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

Here's the code I've written:

```
def no_steps(start,target,sofar):
    if start == target:
        return sofar
    elif start < target and start > 0:
        no_steps(start*2,target,sofar+'*2 ')
        no_steps(start-1,target,sofar+'-1 ')
print(no_steps(2,6,''))
```

May I know what am I doing wrong and is there any issue with the code?

Comment: You are ignoring the return value of the two recursive calls. You need to combine them in some way before returning a value. (Probably returning the minimum of the two?)

Comment: *All* recursion in Python is subject to error you are getting, though; it's one reason why you should try *very* hard to find an iterative solution instead of using recursion.

Comment: Code which doesn't do what you want is a terrible way to explain what you actually want. What should the code do?

Comment: Check your return condition: `start*2` or `start-1` will never be equal to 6 when you start with 2.

Comment: @martineau I think this question shouldn't be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My interpretation is: starting from 2 (`start`), which sequence of multiplications by 2 and subtractions by 1 will lead to 6 (`target`) with the least amount of such operations, meaning not exactly always in that order.

On the one side you have a recursion prob (which is what you see in your output) due to missing implementation of correct return statements. On the other, there is also some logic missing to achieve the least amount of computation steps. My combined solution (for the recursion and the minimum num of steps) would be:

```
def no_steps(start, target, sofar):
    if start == target:
        return sofar
    if 0 < start and 0 < target:
        if (target % 2 == 0) and target > start:
            return no_steps(start, target // 2, '*2 ' + sofar)
        else:
            return no_steps(start, target + 1, '-1 ' + sofar)
    return sofar

no_steps(1, 6, '')
'*2 *2 -1 *2 '

no_steps(2, 6, '')
'*2 -1 *2 '

no_steps(3, 6, '')
'*2 '

no_steps(4, 6, '')
'-1 *2 '

no_steps(5, 6, '')
'-1 -1 *2 '

no_steps(6, 6, '')
''

no_steps(7, 6, '')
'-1 '

no_steps(2, 17, '')
'*2 -1 *2 -1 *2 -1 *2 -1 '
```

**EDIT**: fixed the previously flawed logic based on the answer by PabloRuiz.

Comment: 2*2*2 = 8, that's clearly not the target number.

Comment: This does not result in a minimal number of steps. (1->6 can be achieved by doing 1*2*2-1*2 which is one step less)

Comment: didn't downvote, but is true that it doesn't give the minimal number of steps.

Comment: @PabloRuiz now it does.

Comment: @deponovo, Not sure if is true, but it definitely looks better, up

Comment: @PabloRuiz you can try it ;)

Comment: @deponovo, I think is still bad, you can check "no_steps(2, 17, '')"  and compare it with my current posted solution.

Comment: @PabloRuiz indeed my mathematical logic is flawed and yours is correct. Your answer had my +1 already before. But now it is even better. But you are skipping the recursion aspect. Yes there is no good reason to use recursion for this prob, but that's part of the OP's issue. So solving that part is also important. I fixed the logical aspect of my answer.

Comment: @deponovo, Fully agree, thanks! and great answer now combining both reversing the logic as mine and also using the recursion as the question stated. Pity that my rep is still sinking, at this point the question feels like a community effort!

Answer (score -1):

**Don't use recursion** for this problem, I came up with a much better solution reversing the problem:

```
def no_steps(start, target, sofar=''):
    while target != start:
        if target%2 == 0 and target > start:
            target //= 2
            sofar = '*2' + sofar
        else:
            target +=1
            sofar = '-1' + sofar
    print(sofar)
no_steps(2, 17, '')
```

Note that it assumes that target is bigger than start, if is not just change the order of them to be so.

PD **from here a bad answer**, but still the first one I posted:

You need to stop the recursion, you can do something like:

```
def no_steps(start,target, path='', it=0):
    if it < 10 and not reached:
        it+=1
        if start == target:
            print(f'REACHED! in {it} iterations with {path}')
        elif start < 2*target and start > 0:
            no_steps(start*2,target, path=path+'*2', it=it)
            no_steps(start-1,target, path=path+'-2', it=it)
        else:
            print('Start going beyond target')
no_steps(2,6)
```

You can also add an infamous global variable to stop other branches to continue growing, or just design another algorithm.

Comment: Can i know why the negative points for a working solution? I know that is a horrible algorithm but is not my design just the minimal adaptation i could found for the original to work...

Comment: Didn't downvote but your solution is not a real solution but only a compromise since it doesn't handle the wrong setup of the conditions

Comment: @OcasoProtal Can you provide a failure example? so I improve it? and what do you meet with wrong setup?

Comment: I see many problems with the algorithm, like it explores no sense paths like multiply by 2 and substract 2 two times in a bucle. The necesity of a global variable, etc. But it still works...

Comment: @PabloRuiz well, anything that requires more than your hardcoded number of steps (like s= 2, t = 4096) will not work.

Comment: @matszwecja, true, but it is just an example, python has also a recursion limit that is arbitrary, just change it, if you need it....

Comment: @PabloRuiz The solution is quite simple: You just need to add another condition `elif start > target` and move the -1 part there. And in every condition a return would be nice ;)

Comment: @OcasoProtal, if you think that is the solution post it, but i don't think so.

Comment: @PabloRuiz It is some kind of solution (not the optimal one), just take a look at deponovo's answer. I cannot post an answer because this question is now on hold.

Comment: @OcasoProtal, that is not even a valid solution, as it is not in the minimal number of steps, mine it is! (even with all the bad things it has, as infinite exploration of no-sense branches, also mine doesn't necessarily provide equally good solutions, but again this algorithm is not my design!)

Comment: @OcasoProtal I just fixed a bug, so maybe you were right, not sure if you meant that " start < 2*target"

Answer (score -2):

You make a common mistake with recursion, i.e you assume that `return` will collapse all the calls in-between original call and the one that returns something - it won't.

Let's say you run your program for start = 3 and target = 6. `no_steps(start*2,target, path=path+'*2', it=it)` will return a final result - back to the start = 3 call. And then you ignore this result and call `no_steps(start-1,target, path=path+'-2', it=it)`. Which will in turn call your function with start = 4 and 1 and so forth until infinity (or recursion limit, hence the error). Once you have some result, you need to return it all the way up to the original call.

Another problem in your logic is you want to check all the possible options but have no way of catching an infinite loop like 2->4->3->2->4...